# How to format all country phone number in excel

Tags: excel, warnings, phone-number

I was working on the excel file recently. The excel contains the phone number column which is set to the type General.As I need to validate the phone number formats such as:

```
(123) 456-7890
(123)456-7890
123-456-7890
123.456.7890
1234567890
+31636363634
075-63546725
```

But it shows some warning messages for a particular types such as `1234567890 +31636363634`

The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe -- warning message.

Could someone suggest me any solutions that help me to remove this warning message?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYjo4.png]

Comment: Did you try any of the options in the right-click menu?

Comment: Yes, I have tried one method, Click "options -> Error Checking -> uncheck the number to text format" but this method is set to my local machine only. I need it to be common that is when other's open the particular excel the warning message should not be shown.